# Kernel module signing for CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I have exactly same problem as described in http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5007, when compiling kernel and booting from it.

The bug is marked as closed and there's comment saying no change is required.

I don't understand what is the solution:

1. Should I get extrakeys.pub which is for CentOS? 
   OR
2. Should I replace "CentOs" by "redhat" in

   gpg --homedir . --export --keyring ./kernel.pub CentOS > extract.pub

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long investigations I found my problem.

It's caused by the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929176/error-inserting-scsi-wait-scan-invalid-module-format/13951635#13951635).