# Error inserting scsi_wait_scan - Invalid module format

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, initrd

The system is CentOS 6.3.

I've compile a new kernel and the resulting rpm installed on a target machine.
When booting from the kernel I've receive the error in a title of the question.

I've extracted corresponding initramfs and compared output of:

```
   modprobe --dump-modversions /path/to/scsi_wait_scan.ko
```

with entries in corresponding /boot/**symvers**-*. All symbols checksums fit, including of **module_layout**.

Is there a way to extract **symvers** from kernel itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

**Short answer**

The problem was that I installed kernel rpm (B) over already installed kernel rpm (A), 
without removing it first.

**Detaild answer**

`scsi_mod.ko` was owned only by (A). While installing (B), `scsi_mod.ko` was in /lib/modules/. 
When intramfs was created in (B)'s postinstall script. depmod decided that `scsi_wait_scan.ko` depends on `scsi_mod.ko`, while both build against different configurations.

Later when booting the machine, kernel started run initramfs. This in turn modprob'ed `scsi_wait_scan.ko`. modprobe tried loaded as a consiquence `scsi_mod.ko`, which is not appropriate to the current kernel, thus resulting to error I saw.

Comment: when you install same kernel rpm twice isn't there separate module  directories. for example /lib/modules/<kernel_version1>/.. and /lib/modules/<kernel_version1(1)>/...